# JMeter - Get specified links from page

Tags: javascript, regex, jmeter

I would like to get all the links from a page, which match on a specific pattern.

I try to do this with `Regular Expression Extractor` post processor with regex like this: `<a[^>]* href="([^"]*)"`.

I checked response of `GET` command and found, those links are not visible in response, but links are only visible in browser, when **mouse is over text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748).

I would recommend going for [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) instead, the relevant configuration would be something like:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `link`
- CSS/JQuery Expression: `a`
- Attribute: `href`
- Match No: `-1`

[image: JMeter CSS JQuery Extractor]

You will be able to see all the extracted link URLs using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination. See [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) article for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In general when mouse is over text the attribute `title` is used for the text

So in your case if title is after href you the following (group 2 for mouse over text)

```
<a[^>]* href="([^"]*)" title="([^"]*)"
```

and change Template to use second group as `$2$`